# Messages wont go through a simple chat using threads with Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I've been trying to create a simple chat, my idea was to have 2 functions running in a loop on different threads, one is for sending messages and one is for receiving messages, I am prompted to enter messages which means that at least my sending messages thread works, and I also get connection success message but for some reason the messages are not reaching the other end.

this is my code:

server.py:

```
from socket import *
import threading

server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(("", 4444))
server.listen(5)


def acceptmessages():
    while True:
        data = client.recv(2048).decode()
        print(data)

def sendmessages():
    while True:
        msg = input("Enter message > ").encode()
        client.sendall(msg)

client, addr = server.accept()
print("New connection from Address: {0}".format(addr))

threading.Thread(target=sendmessages(), args=()).start()
threading.Thread(target=acceptmessages(),args=()).start()
```

client.py:

```
from socket import *
import threading

client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("10.0.0.7", 4444))


def acceptmessages():
    while True:
        data = client.recv(2048).decode()
        print(data)

def sendmessages():
    while True:
        msg = input("Enter message > ").encode()
        client.sendall(msg)

threading.Thread(target=sendmessages(), args=()).start()
threading.Thread(target=acceptmessages(),args=()).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I called the function in the target field instead of passing the function, so instead of

```
threading.Thread(target=sendmessages(), args=()).start()
threading.Thread(target=acceptmessages(),args=()).start()
```

it needs to be

```
threading.Thread(target=sendmessages).start()
threading.Thread(target=acceptmessages).start()
```